# Setting more than 6 decimal places in HighCharts?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm new to HighStocks API and I'm trying to set 8 decimal places for low numbers(like "0.00000001").

I already tested many ways of formating, but I can't format more than 6 decimal cases with these value below.

I don't know if its a bug from JS or a HighCharts limitaiton, I just want to make this work.

Thanks.

[JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/YKLUQ/357/)

```
$('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'line'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Test'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Decimals'
            }
        },
        plotOptions: {
            line: {
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    formatter: function () {
                        return Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y,8);
                    }
                },
                enableMouseTracking: false
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Test',
            data: [0.00000020,0.00000020,0.00000020,0.00000020]
        }]
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be a limitation of `Highcharts.numberFormat` function - notation with **e** cannot be changed for very small numbers.

You can use `toFixed()` instead:

```
                    formatter: function () {
                        return this.y.toFixed(7);
                    }
```

**Live demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/0cmLcrLp/

Comment: Thank you! Do you know how can I make the value in left be fixed too?

Comment: Or you know how to make the values .toFixed in the tooltip of a candlestick chart?

Comment: Already found. I had to set ".toFixed" in the Highstock.js file.